# Weird output while passing parameter to script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

hi i am passing parameter to my shell script and getting very weird result .Below is this script-:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set the STRING variable
path=$1
echo password | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - abcd  << EOF
cd $path
#write out current crontab
crontab -l > $2
#echo new cron into cron file
echo $3
#echo $3 >> $2
#install new cron file
#crontab mycron
EOF
```

Above works fine, it goes on specified path,and create backup file but when it goes to echo $3 gives wrong result (weird long string i can not show here).But it only gives that output if pass parameter as belw

```
./createNewCron.sh /u/siebel/abcd backing.txt "00 09 * * 1-5"
```

But when i pass string like below it works fine-:

```
./createNewCron.sh /u/siebel/abcd backing.txt "echo hello"
```

Can anyone explain me why? Thanks

Comment: hi who ever voted for close i am asking why my echo command giving wrong result with parameter as "00 09 * * 1-5". why is it not printing that value??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the shell expands `*` thus your script receives all the files in your directory. To display the stars, you need to quote `echo`

```
echo "$3"
```

Comment: @Hervr Le Borgne thanks man i am new to it still need to learn more.